# How to include SpeedButton Glyph in vsf file (VCL Style)

Tags: delphi, button, styles, vcl, glyph

I'm testing the VCL style in Delphi 10.3 Rio and I wonder if there is a way to include my button's glyph in the vsf file and load the glyph directly from the vsf.

Comment: Assuming you would use several buttons for various functions, you would probably not want to have the same glyph on all of them. The styles are meant to unify the look of all UI controls, and work on classes, not instances. The glyphs for individual `TSpeedButton` instances are to be loaded to the `Glyph` property.

Comment: In the Bitmap Style Designer, there is an "Objects" section where I can change the general look of my components in combinaison with style.png. And there is an "Images" section. Can I add my glyph in this section and load them in my application?

Comment: I have never done that myself, but if you click on `Images` a button `Add` appears (on the right side pane), so yes. Then if you duplicate the standard `SpeedButton` as a new one, say, `MySpeedButton`, you can refer to  your own image (Bitmap property) and its coordinate space when you assign various states, e.g. `BitmapPressed`.

Comment: That's what I had in mind. But I don't know in Delphi how to bind to MySpeedButton. There's no StyleLookupName like in FMX.

Comment: It's a couple of years since I looked into this, but the mechanism was then that the style is looked up based on the components class minus the leading 'T'. So, if you create a new class, say `TMySpeedButton`, then the style engine will look for a `MySpeedButton` object in the style file. If you are eager to learn, trace the paint process with a single speedbutton on a form, and create the forms `OnPaint` event to get a starting point to trace from. Reserve plenty of time ;-)